# Change table header title with Jquery in Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a dropdown list, that has information of "week number", so everytime the user changes week in the dropdownList, I would like to reflect that in the header of my kendo grid. I was trying to change the title of the header with jquery but I was not able to resolve the issue.

This is the generated HTML, and the header I would like to change is data-title="ForecastWeek23", so if the user select week number 24, I would like to change it to "Forecast Week 24".

```
    <div id="grdCsmForecast" class="kendoGridHorizontalScroll k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" style="">
   <div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Export to Excel</a></div>
   <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
      <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
         <table role="grid">
            <colgroup>
               <col style="width:80px">
               <col style="width:90px">
               .....................
            </colgroup>
            <thead role="rowgroup">
               <tr role="row">
                  <th role="columnheader" rowspan="2" data-index="0" id="91073bbd-55b7-468c-9dea-7e8856c41af0" class="k-header"></th>
                  <th role="columnheader" colspan="6" data-colspan="6" data-title="Contract Details" id="d012d7e5-982c-453a-9273-fc7484c6a416" class="k-header">Contract Details</th>
                  <th role="columnheader" colspan="3" data-colspan="3" data-title="Current Renewal" id="3dba6f39-b810-4549-a055-442edb1e2f5f" class="k-header">Current Renewal</th>
                  <th role="columnheader" colspan="3" data-colspan="3" data-title="Target" id="82e71379-9b3e-4bf5-9c1d-665e55ecdcb6" class="k-header">Target</th>
                  <th role="columnheader" colspan="3" data-colspan="3" data-title="ForecastWeek23" id="3e47cb9c-f5aa-49ee-bed7-f572730ebb3c" class="k-header">ForecastWeek23</th>
                  <th role="columnheader" colspan="24" data-colspan="24" data-title="Previous Forecasts" id="b7c3976a-d0b2-4e13-b081-c092f801e29a" class="k-header">Previous Forecasts</th>
               </tr>
               <tr role="row">
                  <th role="columnheader" data-field="RecordId" data-title="RecordId" data-index="1" id="bad2d367-deea-471e-9171-774cd03c98eb" class="k-header k-first">RecordId</th>
                  <th role="columnheader" data-field="SaleId" data-title="SaleId" data-index="2" id="89cb9355-de82-4e6c-a24c-91e9c3b22d63" class="k-header">SaleId</th>
                  .......................
               </tr>
            </thead>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="k-grid-content">
      <table role="grid">
      ...................
      </table>
   </div>

</div>
```

I tried this in the databound method of the grid:

```
var weekid = getKendoDdl("ddlForecastWeek", "kendoDropDownList").value();
$("#grdCsmForecast thead [data-field=ForecastWeek23]").html("Forecast Week " + weekid);
```

And this is the definition of my kendo grid:

```
$("#grdCsmForecast").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    autoBind: false,
    noRecords: {
        template: "<p style='padding-top:10px'>No records available.</p>"
    },
    scrollable: true,
    //pageable: true,
    dataBound: onDataBound,
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
        allPages: true,
        fileName: "CSMForecast.xlsx"
    },
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 20,
        input: true,
        numeric: false,
        pageSizes: ["All", 5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        refresh: false
    },
    columns: [
        { title: "", width: "80px", template: $("#comments-template").html(), attributes: { style: "text-align:center; background-color: white;" } },
        {
            title: "Contract Details",
            columns: [
                { field: "RecordId", title: "RecordId", width: "90px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } },
                { field: "SaleId", title: "SaleId", width: "90px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } },
                { field: "IsUpSell", title: "Upsell?", width: "75px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } },
                { field: "BusinessName", title: "Business Name", width: "300px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } },
                { field: "HealthScore", title: "Health Score", width: "95px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } },
                { field: "CurrencySymbol", title: "CCY", width: "50px", attributes: { "class": "contractDetailGridStyle" } }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "Current Renewal",
            columns: [
                { field: "CurrentRenewalNumber", title: "Nr", width: "40px", attributes: { "class": "currentRenewalGridStyle" } },
                { field: "CurrentRenewalDate", title: "Date", width: "80px", attributes: { "class": "currentRenewalGridStyle" } },
                { field: "CurrentRenewalCancellationDate", title: "Canc Date", width: "80px", attributes: { "class": "currentRenewalGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "Total:" }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "Target",
            columns: [
                { field: "TargetTotalContractValue", title: "TCV", width: "75px", attributes: { "class": "targetGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "TargetTotalContractMonths", title: "Months", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "targetGridStyle" } },
                { field: "Target12MonthsContractValue", title: "12Month", width: "75px", attributes: { "class": "targetGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "ForecastWeek23",
            //headerTemplate: getHeader(),
            columns: [
                { field: "ForecastWeekTotalContractValue", title: "TCV", width: "75px", template: $("#forecast-week-tcv").html(), attributes: { "class": "forecastWeekGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "ForecastWeekMonths", title: "Months", width: "70px", template: $("#forecast-weekMonths").html(), attributes: { "class": "forecastWeekGridStyle" } },
                { field: "ForecastWeek12Months", title: "12Month", width: "75px", attributes: { "class": "forecastWeekGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: "Previous Forecasts",
            columns: [
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth1_TotalContractValue", title: "1", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth2_TotalContractValue", title: "2", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth3_TotalContractValue", title: "2", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth4_TotalContractValue", title: "4", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth5_TotalContractValue", title: "5", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth6_TotalContractValue", title: "6", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth7_TotalContractValue", title: "7", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth8_TotalContractValue", title: "8", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth9_TotalContractValue", title: "9", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth10_TotalContractValue", title: "10", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth11_TotalContractValue", title: "11", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth12_TotalContractValue", title: "12", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth13_TotalContractValue", title: "13", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth14_TotalContractValue", title: "14", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth15_TotalContractValue", title: "15", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth16_TotalContractValue", title: "16", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth17_TotalContractValue", title: "17", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth18_TotalContractValue", title: "18", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth19_TotalContractValue", title: "19", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth20_TotalContractValue", title: "20", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth21_TotalContractValue", title: "21", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth22_TotalContractValue", title: "22", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth23_TotalContractValue", title: "23", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " },
                { field: "PrevForecastMonth24_TotalContractValue", title: "24", width: "70px", attributes: { "class": "previousForecastsGridStyle" }, footerTemplate: "#: sum # " }   
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed quotes on the selector. Try this:

```
$("#grdCsmForecast thead [data-title='ForecastWeek23']").html("Forecast Week " + weekid);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I changed but it is still not working and I don't have any error in the console, I am doing it in the onDataBound method of the grid: 

 $("#grdCsmForecast thead [data-field='ForecastWeek23']").html("Forecast Week " + weekid);

Comment: I changed also with this trying to get close of the DOM, but still nothing: $("#grdCsmForecast thead tr th [data-field='ForecastWeek23']").html("Forecast Week " + weekid);

Comment: @MarcosF8 can you reproduce your problem on dojo.telerik.com? On this https://dojo.telerik.com/eSeNaSeZ example it's working.

Comment: @MarcosF8, sorry, my bad. There is no "data-field" attribute in your example, there is "data-title", so you should try `$("#grdCsmForecast thead [data-title='ForecastWeek23']").html("Forecast Week " + weekid);`

Comment: I changed it for: $("#grdCsmForecast thead th[data-title='ForecastWeek23']").html("Forecast Week " + weekid); so changed the data-field for data-title like appers i

Comment: exactly data-title I discovered that as well, thanks